# How to get the Distinct result using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I am trying to distinct my result based on one column but not able to do.
I have multiple tables using which I am counting the bookings and the result currently displayed like below:

[image]

I want result like below:

[image]

The table structure is like this:

[image]

SQL Query:

```
SELECT count(BK.pkBookingID) as TotalBookings, RM.roomID as RoomID 
FROM dbo.tblBooking BK WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingItem BI WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BI.fkBookingID
INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingDateTime BDT WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BDT.fkBookingID
INNER JOIN Enterprise.tblRooms RM WITH (NOLOCK) ON BI.fkItemID=RM.roomID AND RM.fkResourceId=1
WHERE
BK.deleteBooking=0
AND BDT.UTC_bookingEnd > GETUTCDATE()
AND BI.primaryRoom=1
AND BI.Active=1
AND RM.roomID=124
group by RM.roomID
Order by 1 desc
```

Comment: `count(distinct BK.pkBookingID)`?

Comment: all bookingids are already distinct. I want to count only once if multiple bookings present for the same guid.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT BK.TransactionGUID)`?

Comment: [Stop splattering your code with nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)